# Extract mean from dataframe rows

Tags: python, dataframe, nlp, statistics, emotion

I have dataframe type object consist four repeated attributes : introspection, temper, attitude and sensitivity for each instance and their corresponding values as in figure [this example for single row in dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ZYQh.png).
I want extract mean of these values for each attribute across each instance(rows).
Thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 0):

```
df['mean'] = df.apply(lambda row: (row.introspection + row.temper + row.attitude + row.sensitivity)/4.0, axis=1)
```